# process.nextTick error in node.js?

Tags: node.js

[image]

I am getting process.nextTick error on this very basic example of node.js.

Can someone please figure out?
Is node not able to start listening on port 8000?

```
# cat nodejs.js
net = require("net");
s = net.createServer();

net.on('connection', function (c) {
c.end('hello');
});

s.listen(8000);
```

---

```
# node nodejs.js

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/praveen/nodejs.js:4:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're trying to capture an event on the library (`net`), but you should be looking at [the connectionListener argument to createServer](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/net.html#net.createServer). Try this instead:

```js
var net = require("net");

var server = net.createServer(function (c) {
  c.end('Hello!'); // Implicitly fired on 'connection'
});

server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: Node.js is changing so fast that you can't rely on material more than a few months old. Not sure when that presentation was from, but this is how you do it in Node 0.6.

Answer (score 10):

It's a typo in Ryan's slide! :-0

```
s/net.on/s.on/
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who might stumble here looking for why node pukes this error when they try to issue `brunch watch --server`, check and make sure you don't have any other servers running using the same port (i.e. in another shell).