# node js listen EADDRINUSE error for simple httpserver

Tags: node.js, httpserver

I have simple node js http server.

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

If I run

```
node basicserver.js
```

I get

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:642:11)
    at Array.0 (net.js:743:26)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673775/process-nexttick-error-in-node-js) post, but that post seems to be specific to TCP server and not http server. Could anyone please help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The port you are listening to is already being listened by another process. In this case I got a feeling that it is your self. You can do a `ps aux | grep node` and then using `kill <pid>` kill your node process. Beside that you can also try another port.

--Update--

In case if you want to find which process is listening, you can use `netstat -lpn` ( `-l` is to find out the listening ports, `-p` is to include the process name and pid, `-n` is to not to resolve host names, or else it will be slow), to find the processes that are listening on different ports. If there was too many, you can do `netstat -lnp | grep :8888`.

Also can use, `fuser 8888/tcp`, which will show you the process pid and also adding `-k` will kill the process, fastest way ever.

I realized this two commands only work in **linux**.

Comment: FYI, the `nestat -lnp | grep :8888` example has a typo in `netstat`

Answer (score 6):

To kill all the experiments on my machine...

```
 killall node
```

Answer (score 3):

The port you are listening to is already being listened by another process.

When I faced to this error I killed the process using Windows PowerShell (because I used Windows)

1. open the windows powershell
2. type `ps` and then you can get list of processes
3. find the process named `node`, and note the `Id`
4. type `Stop-process <Id>`

I think that it is help for windows users.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem may occur when you try to run the server, but you don't have root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

On my `Linux Mint` only kill by `PID` work for me:

`netstat -nltp | grep 8080` - shows `PID` of using `8080` port, my output:

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27599/node` - `PID` of node dev server is `27599` in my case

and then kill:

`kill -9 <PID>`

`kill -9 27599`

Preamble:

Don't know what a bug, but I am start my WebPack dev server like `npm run dev`:

`webpack-dev-server --hot --host int.loc --port 8080`

And when interrupt him - in terminal by `Ctrl+C` and start it again - he causing same error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8080`, but all time before it work perfect.

`killall node` not helped.

Comment: This one works best cause of not having to read the huge wall of text the accepted answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue with EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1. After checking for Node processes I changed the server ip to 'localhost'. After doing this it started right up. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users: in Powershell, you can use:

```
Stop-Process -Name "ProcessName" -Force
```

In this case `"ProcessName"` would be `"node"`.

More info here: [How to kill a process in windows](https://winaero.com/blog/kill-process-windows-10/)